# Echo term slug op post on archive page

Tags: terms

I want to echo the term slug for each post on an archive page.

To get the term slug i'm using the following code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'type_kennisbank' );
```

That returns me the data that I want:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#18648 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(28) ["name"]=> 
string(10) "Whitepaper" ["slug"]=> string(10) "whitepaper" ["term_group"]=> 
int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(28) ["taxonomy"]=> string(15) 
"type_kennisbank" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0)  
["count"]=> int(3) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["term_order"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

If I want to echo the slug I'm using:

```
echo $terms["slug"]
```

However it returns nothing. I already found a solution to echo the term slug but I'm wondering why my own echo code doesn't return the slug.

Anyone who can explain this?

Comment: `$terms` is an array and each item is an object. E.g. For the data in your question, you can do `echo $terms[0]->slug;` to display the term slug.

Comment: You're welcome. :) And be sure to check Hector's answer, because he's correct - `get_the_terms()` could return a `WP_Error` instance, or that the array could contain two or more items. All the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_the_terms` function returns array of `WP_Term` objects.
So you need to use something like this to echo a single term slug:

```
echo $terms[0]->slug;
```

Also be aware of results of this function. As [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/#return) says it returns:

> Array of WP_Term objects on success, false if there are no terms or the post does not exist, WP_Error on failure.

So you need some checks before trying to echo terms. The following code may help you.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'type_kennisbank' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->slug;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's the solution that I found as well in the Codex. However I only needed to echo the slug to add it as a CSS-class. But I agree about the check in advance before outputting the slug. Thanks!